# Bromwich integral of $1/s^k$ with k real (non integer) and $1<k$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inverse, laplace-transform, contour-integration

Is there a simple way to compute the inverse laplace transform of $1/s^k$ with k non integer using Bromwich integral (basically without using the known laplace transform of $t^n$)?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{-\infty}{\expo{st} \over \pars{-s}^{k}\expo{\ic\pi k}}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
+
\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\expo{st} \over \pars{-s}^{k}\expo{-\ic\pi k}}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
-\expo{-\ic\pi k}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-st} \over s^{k}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
+
\expo{\ic\pi k}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-st} \over s^{k}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
={\sin\pars{\pi k} \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-k}\expo{-st}\,\dd s
\\[3mm]&=
{\sin\pars{\pi k} \over \pi}\,t^{k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-k}\expo{-s}\,\dd s
={\sin\pars{\pi k} \over \pi}\,t^{k - 1}\Gamma\pars{1 - k}
={\sin\pars{\pi k} \over \pi}\,t^{k - 1}\,{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{k}\sin\pars{\pi k}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#000}{\large{t^{k - 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k}}}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you get from $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^k}ds$ to your first line?

Comment: @Toto  [See the contour](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zfB3Y.jpg)

Comment: How do you handle the integral around C4?

Comment: For some reason I find the integral does not have a limit when r tends towards 0 for C4.

$\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}\frac{e^{re^{i\theta}t}}{r^\alpha e^{i\alpha\theta}}ri\theta e^{i\theta}d\theta$
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Toto In $\displaystyle{\large C_{4}}$ we have the limit $\displaystyle{\large\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}{\exp\left(\epsilon{\rm e}^{\ic\theta}\right) \over \epsilon^{k}{\rm e}^{\ic k\theta}}\,\epsilon{\rm e}^{\ic\theta}\ic\,{\rm d}\theta\quad\propto\quad\epsilon^{1 - k} = 0}$ when $\displaystyle{\large \Re\left(k\right) < 1}$.

Comment: Sure but I am mostly interested in the general case with $k>1$